# Ruby - Open file, find and replace multiple lines

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby and was hoping someone could help me figure out how to open a file, then using gsub to find and replace by multiple conditions.

Here's what I got so far but this doesn't seem to work as the 2nd replace var overrides the first:

```
text = File.read(filepath)
replace = text.gsub(/aaa/, "Replaced aaa with 111")
replace = text.gsub(/bbb/, "Replace bbb with 222")
File.open(filepath, "w") {|file| file.puts replace}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change the third line to

```
replace = replace.gsub(/bbb/, "Replace bbb with 222")
```

Answer (score 20):

You're replacing from the original "text" each time, the second line needs to replace the replace:

```
replace = replace.gsub(/bbb/, "Replace bbb with 222")
```

Answer (score 11):

An interesting wrinkle to this is if you don't want to rescan the data, use the block form of gsub:

```
replace = text.gsub(/(aaa|bbb)/) do |match|
  case match
    when 'aaa': 'Replaced aaa with 111'
    when 'bbb': 'Replace bbb with 222'
  end
end
```

This may not be the most efficient way to do things, but it's a different way to look at the problem. Worth benchmarking both ways if performance matters to you.

Comment: Nice, I imagine that also prevents compiling the pattern twice.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one liner

```
IO.write(filepath, File.open(filepath) {|f| f.read.gsub(/aaa|bbb/) {|m| (m.eql? 'aaa') '111' : '222'}})
```

`IO.write` truncates the given file by default, so if you read the text first, perform the regex `String.gsub` and return the resulting string using `File.open` in block mode, it will replace the file's content. Nifty right?

It works just as well multi-line:

```
IO.write(filepath, File.open(filepath) do |f|
    f.read.gsub(/aaa|bbb/) do |m|
      (m.eql? 'aaa') '111' : '222'
    end
  end
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be tempted to write it like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

filepath = '/tmp/test.txt'

File.open filepath, 'w' do |f|
  $<.each_line do |line|
    f.puts line.gsub(/aaa/,
      'Replaced aaa with 111').gsub /bbb/, 'Replace bbb with 222'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another nice extension to @steveRoss's answer above, using variables:

```
aktivBold = 'AktivGrotesk_Bd.ttf'
clarityBold = 'Clarity-Bold.otf'    

files.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)

  replace = text.gsub(/(#{aktivBold}|#{aktivLight}|#{aktivMedium})/) do |match|
      case match
        when aktivBold
            clarityBold
        when aktivLight
            clarityLight
        when aktivMedium
            clarityMedium                       
      end
    end

  File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }

end
```

These are not string literals but variables