# Can we change XML encoding from utf-8 to utf -16?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, utf-8, xsd, utf-16

I have written a code for generating XML with UTF-8 encoding.I always validate the XML with XSD file. In the same code i need UTF-16 encoding. Because one of my XSD file is of UTF-16 encoding.
But in my existing code it is not accepted. it gives following error.

```
FAILED: Fatal error: Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content at filepath/standard.xsd:1.
```

and at line 1 of XSD this tag is defined `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`

How can i validate it with utf-8 encoding?

Is there any way to change UTF-16 to UTF-8 encoding.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the encoding from **utf16 to utf-8** with Iconv

[Call iconv from Ruby 1.8.7 through system to convert a file from utf-16 to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123049/call-iconv-from-ruby-1-8-7-through-system-to-convert-a-file-from-utf-16-to-utf-8)

When you write the new file you can replace the first line with a new header like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

[Ruby - Open file, find and replace multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048678/ruby-open-file-find-and-replace-multiple-lines)

If you need it in the other way then change the endoding in the function.